# Create a Tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I want to create a Tampermoney script that writes something in an input field, if it finds a string on the page. E.g:

If the page contain the string `"life is"`, the script should automatically append `"good"`.

(I want to make this with word detection, so the string "life is", will appear on the page after that the page was accessed)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the `body` as `String` and the input you want to modify

```
<input id='input-id' />

const page = document.body.innerHTML
const input = document.getElementById('input-id')
```

Then check if the value you want is in the page

```
if(page.search('life is') !== -1)
   input.value = 'life is good'
```

Comment: I want to modify an input value if a string is contained by page, no if the input contain the specific string, a mod edited for me this!

Comment: Hey do you still here?

Comment: @MikeyJY, Edit your question to **include a specific, exact example** of the page code you want change, plus what you want the result to be, plus what you have tried.  Understand this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Comment: @MikeyJY I edited the answer